# PHP - How to clear loadHTMLFile() at the beginning of the foreach loop?

Tags: php, dom, foreach

How to clear loadHTMLFile () at the beginning of the foreach loop so that with each subsequent iteration of this loop it does not accumulate **$response** inside **$document**?

There is a **$response** that accumulates the content inside loadHTMLFile on each subsequent iteration into the content from the previous loop,

... I want to start with a "blank" **$document** on each loop.

Here is my code:

```
$responses = [
    "warsztaty" => "http://www.barlewiczki.pl/index.php/galeria/category/29-um-warsztaty-2018",
    "rozpoczecie_roku_szkolnego" => "http://www.barlewiczki.pl/index.php/galeria/category/36-rozpoczecie-roku-szkolnego-2018-2019"
];


foreach($responses as $key=>$response) {
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadHTMLFile('');
    $document->loadHTMLFile($response);
    
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
    $imgs = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@class, 'shadowbox-button')]");
    for ($i=0; $i < $imgs->length; $i++) {
        $img = $imgs->item($i);
        $src = $img->getAttribute("href");
        // do something with $src
        $urls_to_image[] =  'http://www.barlewiczki.pl' . $src;
    }

    // Desired folder structure
    $my_save_dir =  ('zdjecia_barlewiczki/' . $key . "/");
    
    // To create the nested structure, the $recursive parameter 
    // to mkdir() must be specified.
    
    if (!mkdir($my_save_dir, 0777, true)) {
        $my_save_dir =  mkdir('zdjecia_barlewiczki/');
    }

    foreach ($urls_to_image as $url) {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        $filename = basename($url);
        $complete_save_loc = $my_save_dir . $filename;
        $fp = fopen($complete_save_loc, 'wb');
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        fclose($fp);
    } 
    $document->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Comment that lne out, you dont need it. You create a new instance of DOmDocument

Comment: why do you say _There is a `$response` that accumulates the content inside `loadHTMLFile` on each subsequent iteration into the content from the previous loop_? Your code seems to work just fine. Is your real question possibly how to solve for the duplicate `hrefs` you get for each picture?

Comment: berend - exactly :) I get duplicate hrefs

Comment: I pobably know now what is wrong, I need to empty $urls_to_image array at the beginning of each iteration ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try chainging your xpath expression from

```
 $imgs = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@class, 'shadowbox-button')]");
```

to

```
 $imgs = $xpath->query("//div[@class='pg-box3']/a[contains(@class, 'shadowbox-button')]/@href");
```

At leaset for the first url, this resulted in 20 urls correspoinging to the 20 images on the page.